# Forward mysql port to 33060

Tags: networking, mysql, firewall, ufw, port-forwarding

I'm running mysql server on an ubuntu machine on the default port 3306. I now want to access my mysql instance from anothe rmachine via port 33060. I'm trying to forward port 3306 to 33060 in ufw.

By adding:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306-j REDIRECT --to-port 33060
COMMIT
```

to the /etc/ufw/rules.before file

then when I try `sudo ufw reload`
I get the following error

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore v1.6.0: invalid port/service `3306-j' specified
Error occurred at line: 13
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the error message, and you will see that a space is missing between 3306 and -j

```
iptables-restore v1.6.0: invalid port/service `3306-j' specified
```

Try using this code snippet which includes a space.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-port 33060 COMMIT
```